# React hooks toggle setState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

so far I saw two ways to handle toggle

first, set state based on previous state

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(s => !s);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>show: {String(show)}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>BTN</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

second, pass the state directly as the argument

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>show: {String(show)}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>BTN</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

which one is correct? In my understanding the second may not work as set state is async, it may not be able to get the correct state if I click the button several times

Comment: They both work, but, as you point out, the second case might not work properly in async cases (calling after `await`ing another process). Best here to use the first case as it's less prone to error.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The first one is correct:

```
setShow(s => !s);
```

Although the second one **works in this case** it is not correct:

```
// bad code
setShow(!show);
```

Why?

Setting state is asynchronous - but what that really means is that setting state is deferred until re-render.

An example:

```
const [myNum, setMyNum] = useState(0)

const handleUpdate = () => {
  setMyNum(myNum + 1)
}
```

If we call the `handleUpdate` function, the new value of `myNum` is incremented by 1. That works correctly, but what about this:

```
const [myNum, setMyNum] = useState(0)

const handleUpdate = () => {
  setMyNum(myNum + 1)
  setMyNum(myNum + 1)
}
```

You may think that `myNum` is now 2, but it's not, it's still 1.

This happens because the value of `myNum` does not change until re-render, so you're essentially writing this:

```
const handleUpdate = () => {
  setMyNum(0 + 1)
  setMyNum(0 + 1)
}
```

That is why you should **always** provide a function to set state if you **depend on the previous value**.

This works correctly:

```
const handleUpdate = () => {
  setMyNum(p => p + 1)
  setMyNum(p => p + 1)
}
```

`myNum` is now 2.

Even if you're only setting the value once, you should maintain good practice. When your app gets complex and several different actions may set the state at any time, you don't want to be caught out by something you wrote months ago that you never thought was going to matter.